# Projecting from custom SR to EPSG:32632

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, data-interoperability, ifc

I am having hard times trying to figure out how to possibly convert a dataset they gave me in a custom SR into a well known EPSG 32632.

The situation is:

- I received a IFC whose coordinates were unknown to me.
- I imported it into ArcGIS Pro using Data Interoperability letting the tool "guess" the SR for me
- In my scene, the dataset (now a multipatch featureclass) is placed where it should be (in Vicenza, Italy) although Z coordinate is not reliable (but as of now I don't mind). I can confirm this by overlapping the dataset to a Esri Basemap
- I read the SR is recognized as "IFC COORDSYS 0"
- If I set the map SR to EPSG:32632, everything surprisingly stay in place and I don't have the Z issue anymore

Now, I need this dataset to actually be in 32632, but, no matter what I try, the result is all the time a strange "spear-like shape" while it should be a tunnel, or "disappear" from the mapo in 32632.

Here is what I have been trying so far:

- using define projection to overwrite the prj of my multipatch from "IFC COORDSYS 0" to "WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_32N"
- creating an empty multipatch featureclass from scartch assigning the 32632 SR and then copying and pasting the geometries from the original FC to this brand new one
- importing the IFC specifying the 32632 as my SR

I then decided to save the custom projection to a prj and inspecting it to hopefully have a clue of what's going on.

Below are the two prj: the one that I am trying to project from ("IFC COORDSYS 0")*****, and the one I am trying to project to ("WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_32N").

Can you give me a hint to possibly find out a solution to this problem?

***** prj is made through right-clicking the custom SR in the Map properties and then "Save as Projection File..."

**IFC COORDSYS 0**

```
PROJCS["IFC_COORDSYS_0",
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["World_Geodetic_System_of_1984_GEM_10C",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Azimuthal_Equidistant"],
PARAMETER["false_easting",0.0],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0.0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",-71.25807189916667],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",42.41486358638889],
UNIT["MILLIMETER",0.001]]
```

**WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_32N**

```
PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_32N",
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",9.0],
PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
UNIT["Meter",1.0],
AUTHORITY["EPSG",32632]]
```

Comment: Does the Project tool work on the feature class? Try that. If not, try #2 but import the features, rather than copy-paste them.

Comment: @mkennedy Thanks. The pjoect tool does a mess, producing the "spear-like shape" I mentioned. What do you mean by "importing the features"?

Comment: The input IFC coordinate system is...messy--units of millimeters, funky WGS84 definition. Any chance I could get a copy of the data? Esri employee, mkennedy at esri dot com. I'll delete it after testing it. Also try just unprojecting it to WGS84. If it's already messed up in lat/lon, then it'll be bad in UTM too.

Comment: @mckennedy I'd be happy to share the data with you, thanks. Anyway, is it mckennedy at esri dot com? Meanwhile, I'll try unprojecting it.

Comment: Just mkennedy. It may take a week for me to look at it. User conference is this week!